# Why is beautifulsoup altering the format of my xml?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

When I import and export an xml without making any modification to the xml, the output is significantly altered.

I am using beautifulsoup, and this is an example of the code I'm using.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('/Users/bdon/envtest.xml', 'r'), 'lxml')

with open('/Users/bdon/envmod.xml', "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Here is the xml I'm importing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <apps>
    <app name="apache-common">
      <key name="max" value="400"/>
    </app>
    <app name="epci">
      <key name="instance.type" value="apachecommon"/>
      <key name="aoverride.enabled" value="true"/>
    </app>
```

And the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
 <body>
  <config>
   <apps>
    <app name="apache-common">
     <key name="max" value="400">
     </key>
    </app>
    <app name="epci">
     <key name="instance.type" value="apachecommon">
     </key>
     <key name="aoverride.enabled" value="true">
     </key>
    </app>
```

Problems:

- html and body tag have been added?
- key names now have the '/' stripped from the end and a closing key tag has been added after.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: You did make a modification to the XML... you called `prettify()` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor the the `lxml` HTML parser was specified. Change the constructor call to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('/Users/bdon/envtest.xml', 'r'), 'xml')
```

[The documentation on parsing XML is here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id16).

Comment: It is. It's also an HTML parser. "lxml" causes it to run in HTML mode, "xml" in XML mode. [You can find the list of parsers and modes and how to set them up here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `'html.parser'` then `BeautifulSoup` will not change the format of your code.

**Demo**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <apps>
    <app name="apache-common">
      <key name="max" value="400"/>
    </app>
    <app name="epci">
      <key name="instance.type" value="apachecommon"/>
      <key name="aoverride.enabled" value="true"/>
    </app>
    </apps>
    </config>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<apps>
<app name="apache-common">
<key name="max" value="400"></key>
</app>
<app name="epci">
<key name="instance.type" value="apachecommon"></key>
<key name="aoverride.enabled" value="true"></key>
</app>
</apps>
</config>
```

Comment: Am i missing something? This looks completely changed. The formatting is all gone when you print it.

Comment: Using html.parser will change the case of the tags to lowercase.